Movement and rotation in the new Input manager
I'm trying to set up controls for the player using the keyboard-mouse and Gamepad.
Code for the Input manager
When playing on a gamepad, the game looks good, but if you use a keyboard-mouse, then immediately the control is depressing. How can I improve player control and rotation?
Game scene
If you change the rotation speed, you can achieve a good result for the keyboard-mouse, but then the control on the gamepad suffers.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
    
public class PlayerControllerBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerConfig _playerConfig;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _playerRb;
     
    public PlayerConfig PlayerConfig { get => _playerConfig; set => _playerConfig = value; }
    public Rigidbody PlayerRb { get => _playerRb; protected set => _playerRb = value; }

    public Vector3 MoveDirection { get; protected set; }
    public Quaternion MoveRotation { get; protected set; }

    private Vector3 value;

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        MoveDirection = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        _playerRb.AddForce(new Vector3(MoveDirection.x*_playerConfig.PlayerSpeed,0,MoveDirection.y * _playerConfig.PlayerSpeed));
    }

    protected void Move(Vector3 value)
    {
        _playerRb.AddForce(new Vector3(value.x*_playerConfig.PlayerSpeed, 0, value.y * _playerConfig.PlayerSpeed));
    }

    public void OnRotation(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        value = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        MoveRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, value.x * _playerConfig.PlayerRotationSpeed, 0);
    }

    protected void PlayerRotate(Quaternion rotation)
    {
        value.Normalize();
        if (Mathf.Abs(value.x) > 0.001f || Mathf.Abs(value.y) > 0.001f)
        {
            _playerRb.MoveRotation(_playerRb.rotation * rotation);
        }
    }
}


There are options you can add to the move for a necessary  option a scale vector processor whether you lessen some or make some bigger. Choice is yours

Go to edit ==> project settings ==> input manager, and change the sensitivity values for mouse X and mouse Y, or the first Horizontal and Vertical input axes.
